# What are the difference of the two following definitions of homotopy equivalence and homoemoprhism?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

**Definition 1** Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. $X$ and $Y$ are of the same **homotopy type**, written as $X\simeq Y,$ if there exists continous maps $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\rightarrow X$ such that $f\circ g\sim \operatorname{id}_Y$ and $g\circ f\sim \operatorname{id}_X$.

**Definition 2** Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. A map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a **homoeomorphism** if it is continuous and has an inverse $f^{-1}:Y\rightarrow X$ which is also continuous.

What is difference between these two definitions because it look like they are the same thing.  $g$ in the first definition and $f^{-1}$ in the second definition looks like the same thing.

Comment: Well, $f^{-1} \circ f$ **is** the identity, but $g \circ f$ **is homotopic to** the identity. There is a clear difference in the two definitions : infact, it is also clear that being of the same homotopy type is (strictly) weaker than being homeomorphic.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг.  A simple example please.

Comment: An interval, say on the real line, is homotopy equivalent to the a single point, because you can consider the function $f$ to be constant i.e. taking the entire interval to the point, and $g$ taking the single point to anywhere on the interval, then $f \circ g$ is the identity on $Y$, and $g \circ f$ is a constant function on the interval, which is homotopic to the identity map via a stretching. Of course, any interval is not homeomorphic to a single point, because they have different cardinalities.